# Mailchimp add subscriber to all groups

Tags: mailchimp

I've been trying to find some information on how to do this and I'm beginning to think that it is impossible. I'd like some input from others before I give up the idea completely.

I have dropdown select on my form that allows the user to select which group they want to sign up for.

```
<select name="group[3893]" class="form-control" id="mce-group[3893]">
<option value="">What would you like to hear about?</option>
<option value="1">Zumba</option>
<option value="2">Pilates</option>
<option value="">All Classes</option>
</select>
```

I have no idea what value to assign to the All Classes option. Is it possible to sign the user up to both groups?

I think that the only way around this is to create a third group called All Classes and subscribe them to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that will work, and which one is best depends on your use case. The differentiating point is what happens to someone who chooses "all classes" when a new type of class is offered? Let's say John subscribes and clicks "all classes". A few months later you add barre classes to your selection. Should John receive those emails?

If so: you'll want to create an "all classes" group. This is [how MailChimp themselves handle this](http://mailchimp.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe?u=a3656c37c06d9298dc574e96f&id=be646dcff8).

If not: you'd probably want to use javascript to make selecting "all classes"  check all of the interest groups before the form submission.